# Compile error without brackets surrounding ternary operator when creating Tuples in C#

Tags: c#, tuples, ternary-operator, c#-7.0

I have encountered an error in C# with the new Tuple feature. If I use a ternary operator to determine a value for the tuple I must surround it with brackets. I didn't expect this, because in method calls this isn't the case.

Are there any reasons for this or is it a bug?

Setup:

- Visual Studio 2017
- .Net Standard 1.6 Class Library
- System.ValueTuple (v4.3.0 - from Nuget)

My Code:

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Ok { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //
        // FROM OBJECT
        //
        Test obj = new Test() { Ok = true, Text = "asdf" };

        StringMethod(true, obj.Ok ? obj.Text : "fsda");      // <-- OK
        var result1 = (true, obj.Ok ? obj.Text : "fsda");    // <-- Error
        var result2 = (true, (obj.Ok ? obj.Text : "fsda"));  // <-- OK (Same as line above, but with addional brackets)


        //
        // FROM OTHER TUPLE
        // 
        var tuple = OtherTuple();

        StringMethod(true, tuple.ok ? tuple.text : "fdsa");     // <-- OK
        var result3 = (true, tuple.ok ? tuple.text : "fdsa");   // <-- Error
        var result4 = (true, (tuple.ok ? tuple.text : "fdsa")); // <-- OK (Same as line above, but with addional brackets)
    }

    public void StringMethod(bool state, string anyString)
    {

    }

    public (bool ok, string text) OtherTuple()
    {
        return (true, "asdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/16834

Comment: Also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17135

Answer (score -3):

I think the var cannot define that you are trying to set the value of a Tuple on this line

```
 var result3 = (true, tuple.ok ? tuple.text : "fdsa");
```

Maybe if you be more clear like this:

```
 var result3 = Tuple.Create(true, tuple.ok ? tuple.text : "fdsa");
```

This makes the code easy to read.